# Differences in Socket-connections between Windows & Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, sockets, ubuntu

My Java-Application communicates via a socket-connection with another device.
I send a response and then i get a response.

Under Windows: Request sent -> OK received as Response.
Under Ubuntu: Request sent -> NOT OK received as Response.

Of course i checked this case with wireshark,
but the requests are exactly the same. Every byte.

That is why i think, that the difference is in the socket-connection-construction.

Has anyone the solution to my problem? ^^"

Comment: I believe there are no such differences in usability of java socket on Linux and Windows... Could You post some snippet of Your code?

Comment: Socket in java are same for all platform like Windows, linux, mac etc

Answer (score 0):

Sockets in Java perform identically anywhere the JVM is installed. However, your particular OS might having something different in terms of networking.